# How to make a UIView have an effect of transparent gradient?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, gradient

I want to make a `UIView` have an effect of transparent gradient from the middle to the left and right. Like in this example:

[image]

The word `籍` has the desired effect. This view is achieved by the class [MarqueeLabel](https://github.com/cbpowell/MarqueeLabel-Swift). I examined the source code, it is likely implemented by class `CALayer`.

Comment: You just use **opacity**.  Annoyingly it's named **alpha** for views but **opacity** for CALayer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `CAGradientLayer` as following.

```
gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradientLayer.frame = baseView.bounds;
gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.5,0.0);
gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPointMake(0.5,1.0);
gradientLayer.locations = @[@(0.0), @(0.2), @(1.0)];
gradientLayer.colors = @[(id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.9].CGColor,
                         (id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.3].CGColor,
                         (id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.0].CGColor];
[baseView.layer addSublayer:gradientLayer];
```

`CAGradientLayer` supports several properties to make natural gradient, such as setting gradient direction by `startPoint` and `endPoint`, changing color curve by `locations` and `colors`.

You also make a transparent effect by using alpha channel of color.

Comment: The question was flagged objective-c, not swift.

Comment: @catalandres okay. i see. Leo already suggests a swift version. so i might not edit my answer. :-) If there is anyone who needs objective-c version, it will be help.

Comment: Thx for your answer. I rewrite code with swift by your thought, and succeed. :-) Thx, again.

Comment: I had to change the last line to `self.submitButtonBackground.layer.mask = gradientLayer;` to make it work in iOS 11

Answer (score 23):

In Swift 4: for top to bottom transparent gradient.

```
let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.0)
gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.6)
let whiteColor = UIColor.white
gradient.colors = [whiteColor.withAlphaComponent(0.0).cgColor, whiteColor.withAlphaComponent(1.0).cgColor, whiteColor.withAlphaComponent(1.0).cgColor]
gradient.locations = [NSNumber(value: 0.0),NSNumber(value: 0.2),NSNumber(value: 1.0)]
gradient.frame = gradientView.bounds
gradientView.layer.mask = gradient
```

Comment: Just perfect! Thank you.

Answer (score 19):

Screenshot

[image]

Swift code

```
let mask = CAGradientLayer()
mask.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.5)
mask.endPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 0.5)
let whiteColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
mask.colors = [whiteColor.colorWithAlphaComponent(0.0).CGColor,whiteColor.colorWithAlphaComponent(1.0),whiteColor.colorWithAlphaComponent(1.0).CGColor]
mask.locations = [NSNumber(double: 0.0),NSNumber(double: 0.2),NSNumber(double: 1.0)]
mask.frame = label.bounds
label.layer.mask = mask
```

Answer (score 8):

Swift 3:

```
let mask = CAGradientLayer()
mask.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)
mask.endPoint = CGPoint(x:1.0, y:0.5)
let whiteColor = UIColor.white
mask.colors = [whiteColor.withAlphaComponent(0.0).cgColor,whiteColor.withAlphaComponent(1.0),whiteColor.withAlphaComponent(1.0).cgColor]
mask.locations = [NSNumber(value: 0.0),NSNumber(value: 0.2),NSNumber(value: 1.0)]
mask.frame = view.bounds
view.layer.mask = mask
```

Answer (score 4):

Use clear color instead of set the alpha value.

```
let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)
gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0.5)
gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.clear.cgColor, UIColor.white.cgColor, UIColor.white.cgColor]
gradientLayer.locations = [0, 0.2, 1]
gradientLayer.frame = gradientView.bounds
gradientView.layer.mask = gradientLayer
```